# Fancy file slurping in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, scope, syntactic-sugar, deobfuscation

I was looking into efficient ways to read files in Perl and came across this very interesting one liner:

```
my $text = do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $file; <> };
```

My question is: How exactly does this work? Normally when slurping a file you set `$/ = undef`, but I don't see how this does that. This little piece of code is proving to be very difficult to wrap my head around.

What would be a simplified breakdown and explanation for this?

---

Now that I know how it works, lets get real fancy!

Not that this code has any real use; it's just fun to figure out and cool to look at. Here is a one-liner to slurp multiple files at the same time!!!

```
my @texts = map { local (@ARGV, $/) = $_; <> } @files;
```

Comment: perl allows to assign multiple variables in a single assignment (don't know how it's properly called): `($a, $b, $c) = (1, 2)`. `$c` here would end up `undef`

Comment: That is horrible. You have to ask what it does, so don't duplicate it

Comment: This line of code actually appears to be a commonly used piece of Perl code.  I've seen it in more than one place which is what lead me to ask this question.

Comment: That's what horrible about it... ;-) Perl is full of these neat little shortcuts that are too horrible to use and too neat not to...

Comment: Don't need `map` for multiple files.  `my @texts = do { local (@ARGV, $/) = @files; <> };`

Comment: (>\*o\*)>   *\*mind blown\**   <(\*o\*<)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
local (@ARGV, $/) = $file;
```

is the same as

```
local @ARGV = ( $file );
local $/    = undef;
```

`<>` then reads from files mentioned in `@ARGV`, i.e. from `$file`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, then the `do {}` just returns whatever the value of the last evaluated expression is, which would be the value of `<>` or the contents of the file. Thanks @charoba!

Comment: @jwrona1992, The point of `do` is to limit the scope in which `@ARGV` and `$/` are changed.